# Do you need to make the noun that describe two subjects in a sentence plural?

Tags: grammar

For example : Both the salty and sweet _ are available. ( variation ) or ( variations )

Comment: Depends. If you have one of each, "Both ... variation are available," because the two are available.

Comment: So if "the salty" or "the sweet" subject has many variations then the correct answer would be variations ?

Comment: "Variation" seems an odd word here - they're not variations, they're entirely different flavors. Maybe use "variety" or "flavor"?

Comment: Both the red car and the blue car have scratches. The red and blue cars both have scratches. I'd not use 'Both the red and blue car/s ...'.

Comment: @StuartF They're variations of the object being flavored. Analogously, if you were talking about cars, you could say "the full-electric and hybrid variations"

Comment: @YosefBaskin I don't think you need to have only one of each variation in order for the singular to work.  But you'd need to repeat the determiner: *Both **the** hard-top and **the** convertible **model** are being assembled in Detroit.*